# Mutation that creates an item that contains an array of different other items

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am working in a GraphQL side project to learn a bit more about it.
I am doing a simple photo / albums site. I can create an upload different photos and I can also create albums. What I want to do now is:
Create an album with a name, description... and I will show all the pictures you have uploaded to the page. You should be able to select as many as you want and those pictures will be linked to that album.

The problem I am facing is that I can't make this relationship working.
I am using GraphQL with Yoga and Prisma and Apollo on the frontend.

I'll show you here the files I have:

datamode.graphql

```
type Picture {
  id: ID! @id
  title: String!
  description: String!
  image: String!
  largeImage: String
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
}

type Album {
  id: ID! @id
  title: String!
  description: String
  coverImage: String
  largeCoverImage: String
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
  pictures: [Picture]
}
```

schema.graphql

```
#import * from './generated/prisma.graphql'

type Mutation {
  createPicture(title: String, description: String, image: String, largeImage: String): Picture!
  createAlbum(title: String, description: String, coverImage: String, largeCoverImage: String pictures:[String]): Album!
  updateAlbum(id: ID!, title: String, description: String, coverImage: String, largeCoverImage: String): Album!
}
```

mutation.js

```
const Mutations = {
  async createAlbum(parent, args, ctx, info) {
    const album = await ctx.db.mutation.createAlbum({
      data: {
        ...args
      }
    }, info)
    return album;
  }
};

module.exports = Mutations;
```

Then, on the frontend where I have the form to submit the new album creation, I have the mutation defined using the graphql-tag:

```
const CREATE_ALBUM_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation CREATE_ALBUM_MUTATION(
    $title: String!
    $description: String
    $coverImage: String
    $largeCoverImage: String
    $pictures: [String]
  ) {
    createAlbum(
      title: $title
      description: $description
      coverImage: $coverImage
      largeCoverImage: $largeCoverImage
      pictures: $pictures
    ) {
      id
    }
  }
`;
```

And then I have my form wrapped around the Mutation component with the onSubmit method:

```
      <Mutation mutation={CREATE_ALBUM_MUTATION}>
        {(createAlbum, { loading, error }) => (
          <Form onSubmit={async e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const res = await createAlbum({
              variables: {
                ...this.state,
                coverImage: this.state.coverImage || RandomFallbackCoverImageAlbum()
              }
            });
            console.log('response', res);
          }}>
```

With this code, when I submit a new album, I got this error:

```
Error: Variable "$_v0_data" got invalid value { title: "qqqqw", description: "qqqqw", coverImage: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1416169607655-0c2b3ce2e1cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80", largeCoverImage: "", pictures: ["cjyehm6qty18w0b53s501aqiy", "cjyei64yyyd690b53pxtxzona", "cjytt66xhz0sx0b53zqm9jiag"] }; Field "0" is not defined by type PictureCreateManyInput at value.pictures.
Variable "$_v0_data" got invalid value { title: "qqqqw", description: "qqqqw", coverImage: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1416169607655-0c2b3ce2e1cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80", largeCoverImage: "", pictures: ["cjyehm6qty18w0b53s501aqiy", "cjyei64yyyd690b53pxtxzona", "cjytt66xhz0sx0b53zqm9jiag"] }; Field "1" is not defined by type PictureCreateManyInput at value.pictures.
Variable "$_v0_data" got invalid value { title: "qqqqw", description: "qqqqw", coverImage: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1416169607655-0c2b3ce2e1cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80", largeCoverImage: "", pictures: ["cjyehm6qty18w0b53s501aqiy", "cjyei64yyyd690b53pxtxzona", "cjytt66xhz0sx0b53zqm9jiag"] }; Field "2" is not defined by type PictureCreateManyInput at value.pictures.
```

I think that I am not referring the Picture model properly on the CreateAlbum mutation but I am struggling big time in understanding how it should be...
Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would think your main issue is that you haven't established a relationship between pictures and albums in your datamodel.prisma (or .graphql as you have).

```
type Picture {
  ...
  albums: [Album] @relation(name: "PictureToAlbum")
}

type Album {
  pictures: [Picture] @relation(name: "PictureToAlbum")
}
```

As you seem to be creating the pictures before the album and allowing for the possibility that one photo can belong to many albums I have the Pictures's "albums" property as a nullable array.

This should satisfy the relation.

When you define your mutations and when creating your "CREATE_ALBUM_MUTATION" you have your input as `pictures:[String]` where the relationship would be expecting `pictures:[ID]`.

It is always easiest to test mutations like this in Playground as you can easily see the expected inputs and get any errors directly.